# In the volusion API URL interface how can you have multiple where clauses

Tags: vb.net, api, volusion

We are running VB.Net from a Windows workstation and encountering an issue with the Volusion API interface.

It works when we use a single where_column/where_value clause but not when we need multiples.

> Login=%user%&EncryptedPassword=ppp&API_Name=Generic\Orders&SELECT_Columns=*&WHERE_Column=o.OrderStatus&WHERE_Value=Shipped

works but

> Login=jchar@aaatex.com&EncryptedPassword=8B48EF453FD2C9F7BC3E82860E7A9F39A7C506A51BFC1637C7D7DE621D70B2C8&API_Name=Generic\Orders&SELECT_Columns=*&WHERE_Column=o.OrderStatus&WHERE_Value='Shipped'&WHERE_Column=o.OrderID&WHERE_Value=3782

does not.

We get this message

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one where clause in a query through the Volusion API as a URL query string. You can however run a saved text file with a SQL query from your "Generic" folder or even create one on the fly with ASP.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you point me to where the on the fly query is documented?  We are not using ASP.  It is a Windows Desktop App. These WHERE clauses have variable data like the orderId so I am not sure a saved query would work unless it can take variables.